# Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in to Game Center

Tags: android, google-play

Что сделал:

1. добавил линк Dev Console (game services)
2. включил  App_id в app/manifest
3. реализовал BaseGameActivity and GameHelper  (GitHub)
4. добавил google-play-services либу

log:

```
GameHelper: **** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
 GameHelper: **** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
 GameHelper: **** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
 GameHelper: ****     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
 GameHelper: **** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
 GameHelper: **** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are 
 GameHelper: ****     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
 GameHelper: ****     a test account.
```

1. App_id из консоли брал, 100% верно.
2. Юзаю тестовый аккаунт
3. SHA1 и package name 100% верны

Что делать?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В [консоли](https://code.google.com/apis/console) оказывается надо было SHA1 вводит в разные Client ID.

Изначально я в одном Client ID добавил SHA1 для дебаг-ключа и для релизного - не работало.
Когда создал два различных Client ID, то стало работать.